# MySQL reinstalled, but root password still there and I forgot it

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I forgot my root password in MySQL 5.1 on Windows 7
I uninstalled and deleted the MySQL directory in Program Files

Then I installed 5.5, but get error 1045, saying: `Access denied for user: 'root@localhost'`

I thought that uninstalling MySQL, and reinstalling would allow me to create a new root password, but apparently not.  Please help!

Comment: I have already tried the solution provided at the following url with no success: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

Answer (score 11):

Actually even after uninstalling the MySQL the data still remains in the directory which is not deleted by itself. So if you want to reinstall it from scratch then follow these simple steps:

Using Windows 7/8, here's what you need to do:

1. Uninstall MySQL using the uninstaller
2. Delete `C:\Program Files\MySQL`
3. Delete `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`
4. Delete `C:\ProgramData\MySQL`
5. Delete from any Users' AppData folders. Example: `C:\Users\rdoverby\AppData\Roaming\MySQL`
6. Reinstall MySQL.

And then it will hopefully work fine!

Comment: Not sure why the uninstaller isn't either unified or gives the option to leave old data behind like a lot of application do, SO I COULD UNCHECK IT =)

Answer (score 9):

There's a guide on mysql.com called [Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows).

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that.  When I entered the command line in step 6, it just hung...

Comment: @Tim: allright, tough luck :( Did you try the "generic instructions" too?

Comment: Actually, I have not, but they're not too clear to me.  I'm new to MySQL

Comment: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --skip-grant-tables

Comment: They're using `mysqld-nt.exe` (not `mysqld`), does that make any difference?

Comment: And also, did you make sure to execute the command as an admin?

Comment: It didn't hang; it's running.  Just leave that window as it is and open a different command line window to complete the process.

Comment: I don't have a file called mysqld-nt, only mysqld

Comment: Seun, I just typed in: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" –init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt    and it's running (hanging...)

Comment: Just added --console, getting error 32.  saying that another program is using InnoDB file.  how do I close that?

Comment: @Tim: look at step 2 in the guide for windows, that should do it.

Comment: Says it's STARTING, and doesn't allow me to stop it

Comment: @chelmertz - should I restart my pc?

Comment: I figured out the solution:
When uninstalling MySQL, it's not enough to uninstall and delete the MySQL folder in Program Files. 
I also had to delete the MySQL folder in Program Data, which is a hidden folder on the C drive

thanks all

Comment: TIm's comment should be marked way up. I tried all the differing options in the linked guides and none worked. Nuking and reinstalling is the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Tim's solution is the only thing that works! you rock!

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to use the init-file option to mysqld

Add either

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'blah' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or preferably

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('blah');
```

to a file say /reset.mysqld

Edit your **/etc/my.cnf** to point to this file

```
[mysqld]
....
init-file=/reset.mysqld
...
```

Restart mysqld, remove /reset.mysqld and revert your my.cnf to what it was before.

Answer (score 3):

1. First uninstall MySQL Server
2. Delete MySQL Server Application Data folder at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` (Windows XP).
3. Re-install MySQL Server via the MySQL installer.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me just fine,

Now you can do this using the [MYSQL installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/).I downloaded the 250MB file. There you can remove all the tools (In cases they can be out dated) as well as all the MYSQL files (NOTE: These are asked to remove after uninstalling the existing tools) that causes these kind of problems. Then again you can install them using the same SQL installer.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the MySql than Go to C drive unhide the program data folder & delete the MySql folder which is lies inside it ..now reinstall the MySQL again